# Smooth lines on stacked line plot python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to generate a stacked line chart. Is it possible to smooth the lines?

```
y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7= y1_dict.values(), 
y2_dict.values(), y3_dict.values(), y4_dict.values(), 
y5_dict.values(), y6_dict.values(), y7_dict.values()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.stackplot(y1_dict.keys(), y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7) 
plt.xticks(y1_dict.keys(), times, rotation="vertical") 
#times holds str representations of minutes in 15 min intervals in a 24 hr period
plt.xlabel("x-axis")
plt.ylabel("y-axis")
plt.title("title")
plt.show()
```

Here is a picture of the graph below:

[image: stacked line graph]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data to do this. A simple option would just be a mean filter. For example, I have the following data.

[image]

I then filter it with a length 5 mean filter. I use scipy's convolve function to do this.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve
smoothed = convolve(data, [1/5] * 5, mode='valid')
```

Which results in this signal.

[image]